# Angular custom cookie not sent in headers?

Tags: angular, typescript, cookies

I am using Angular and the package NGX Cookie Service to create custom cookie **in the front end**. And I want it to be attached in the HTTP Request when sending such to the backend.

This is how I set it in the browser:

```
 private SetCookieAfterLogin() {
        let cookie = this.loginOutput.Token;
        this.cookieService.set('authCookie', cookie, { sameSite: 'Lax'});
    }
```

And when I try to execute this http method which calls the API:

```
getAllUsers(): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.get<IGetUserModel[]>(this.getAllUsersUrl, {withCredentials:true}).
        pipe(
            tap(data => console.log('All:',JSON.stringify(data))),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
    }
```

... while inspecting the HTTP Request headers, the cookie was not attached. Is this a normal behavior? If so - what are the rules: which cookies are attached and which are not? Should I  use HTTP Interceptor?

**Both the APIs and the frontend client run on localhost** for now, but different ports, if this matters for the cookie and its options.

Comment: I think you might want HTTP Interceptors: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

Comment: Since both frontend and backend are running on localhost , the domain should match . You can also try adding domain:'localhost' while setting cookie parameters

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually in my code. No cookie was created, because of empty data in this.loginOutput.Token due to async. This is now fixed and my cookie is properly inside the headers. Thank you.